# Issue Plotting Torus Link

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, knots

I'm having an issue plotting torus links in *Mathematica*. What I'm trying to generate is a (2,8) torus link like the one in [the picture in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number):

[image: 2,8 torus link]

using equations such as those outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot).

However, I appear to only get half of the respective torus link.

```
a = 1; d = 4; p = 2; q = 8;
ParametricPlot3D[{(a*Sin[q*t] + d)*Sin[p*t], (a*Sin[q*t] + d)*
Cos[p*t], a*Cos[q*t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
PlotRange -> All] /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.2, rest]
```

[image: my attempt]

(`a` and `d` are parameters that control the width of the tube and the distance of the curve from the origin respectively, outlined [here](http://ocw.nctu.edu.tw/course/scientific-computation-and-visualization/scv-topic5.pdf).)

Can anyone explain why I am only seeing half of the link?

Comment: You're only plotting one set of parametric equations and you can see in the image that you don't *expect* there to be any intersections so the smooth parametric equations clearly can't generate the structure you want. On the other hand, it ought to be clear that the others may be generated via a simple rotation in the x-y plane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second torus is created by a rotation of $\pi/4$  (around `{0, 0, 1}`):

```
R = RotationMatrix[Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}];
torus = {(a*Sin[q*t] + d)*Sin[p*t], (a*Sin[q*t] + d)*Cos[p*t], a*Cos[q*t]};
ParametricPlot3D[{torus, R.torus} // Evaluate, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Blue}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Knot]

Answer (score 9):

Here's I think a generalization of what Ulrich gave to an arbitrary $(p, q)$ torus (if I read Wikipedia right):

```
plotPQTorus[{p_, q_}, a : _?NumericQ : 1, d : _?NumericQ : 4, 
  ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Block[{t},
  ParametricPlot3D[
    Evaluate@
     Table[
      RotationMatrix[
        i*2 \[Pi]/q, {0, 0, 1}].{(a*Sin[q*t] + d)*
         Sin[p*t], (a*Sin[q*t] + d)*Cos[p*t], a*Cos[q*t]},
      {i, 0, If[Divisible[q, p], p - 1, 0]}
      ],
    {t, 0, 2*Pi},
    PlotRange -> All,
    ops
    ] /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.2, rest]
  ]
```

Here are a few plots:

```
Table[plotPQTorus[{p, Fibonacci[q]}, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> None], {p, 1, 4}, {q, 2, 6, 2}] // Grid
```

[image]

Note that relatively prime things are single connected loops (as Wikipedia suggests they should be)

Answer (score 4):

The (1,4) torus knot is known to `KnotData[]`, so we can use that to build the (2,8) knot:

```
knot14 = First[KnotData[{"TorusKnot", {1, 4}}, "ImageData"]];

Graphics3D[MapThread[Insert[##, {2, 1}] &,
                     {{knot14, MapAt[RotationTransform[π/4, {0, 0, 1}], knot14, {1}]}, 
                      Directive[Specularity[1, 10], #] & /@ {Blue, Red}}], 
           Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}]
```

[image: (2,8) knot]